# Grouping neighbours in separate arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fingerprint

I have an annotated 512x512x3 fingerprint image, with the annotations being the positions of loops and deltas in the image.  Red denotes loop, and blue denotes delta.

[image: Red denotes loop, blue denotes delta.]

I need to find the position of these points. I can do this using `impixel()`, but I wanted a more automated approach.

I did the following:

```
x=[];
y=[];
for i = 1:512
    for j = 1:512
        marked = im(i,j,:);
        if marked(:,:,1)==255
            x=[x i];
            y=[y j];
        end
    end
end
x = unique(x);
y = unique(y);
```

and got the positions of the pixels where the color red is the position of the loops.

My array `y` holds the y coordinates of all the red pixels, like this:

```
[116 117 118 119 120 121 122 191 192 193 194 195 196 197]
```

At first glance, it is clear that the values can be grouped into 2 groups, for the two red points. But I am unsure how to divide the values into two groups. I thought about creating a threshold using the mean of the values, but that might not work if the points are close by.

Any help might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance how many red points there will be (2 in the example), you could use kmeans -

```
y_groups = kmeans(y',2);
```

If you don't know the number of groups, then if the points always contain the same number of pixels, you could work it out from that - in the example there are 7 pixels per point so

```
npts = numel(y) / 7;
y_groups = kmeans(y',npts);
```

We could add a loop afterwards to get the mean of each group (there are many other ways you could look into for this too e.g. grpstats):

```
y_means = NaN(npts,1);
for I = 1:npts
    y_means(I) = mean(y(y_groups == I));
end
```